# What do the lyrics of "Juliet" by Cloudnone and Matt Van mean?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, electronic-music

There is a song of the genre Future Garage called Juliet by Cloudnone and Matt Van, and the lyrics seem to be about a man building a spaceship to find his lost lover in space, but upon further review, they seem to allude to something deeper about death and grief.   What are your thoughts on this?  Do the lyrics really seem to allude to something bigger than what they appear to be about, and if so, *what* does it allude to?

Song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3bkd2_uGJ0

[Lyrics](https://genius.com/Cloudnone-and-matt-van-juliet-lyrics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve worked with monstercat many many times.
I know cloud pretty well, I’m fairly sure I can guess

I’ll go ahead and say that this song is about suicide after losing a lover.
I didn’t make this song with cloud, but I have before.
I hope that answered your question.

Cloud often refers to death as space,
As well as, in the song Matt sings
“I’ll find you in a better place”

Comment: My idea was suicide too. My second theory was that the guy is high on drugs, or even dreaming, but that doesn't quite match the lyrics: "I've had this plan" refers to a one-time act, and "I've got this feeling you'll be there when I land" suggests he is not going back to where he took off => this is a one-way journey to a destination where he expects to meet her, i.e. death.